# C++ how to show Else statement

Tags: c++

this code displays if the two integers are Multiples, Factors, or Neither of the two. Everything is set in Multiple and Factor sections but the Neither won't show in the output. Can someone explain and help me how this simple trick should be done.

```
int a;
int b;

cin >> a;
cin >> b;

if (a>b){
    for (int i = b; i < a; i++){
        if ((b % i == 0) && (a % i == 0)){
            cout << "Multiple";
        }
    }
} else if (b > a){
    for (int i = a; i < b; i++){
        if ((a % i == 0) && (b % i == 0)){
            cout << "Factor";
        }
    }
} else {
    cout << "Neither";
}
```

Comment: What are you giving as input?

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: You can set a to 1 and b to 1.. As long as a = b, it'll print "Neither"..

Comment: What sets of values have you tried, what results were you expecting with those sets of values as opposed to the results that were being produced? Did you step through your code line by line in a debugger to check your variables at each step?

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: you need to set a flag when you decide that they are factors / multiples. Then uncoditionally test this flag (not in an else clause) and output neither if the falg is not set

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with a flag like: `bool neither = true;` and then in your loops set `neither = false` if the test comes up true (and then `break;` out of the loops since the remaining iterations are not needed), then make your final else: `if(neither) { ...}` instead (note this is a freestanding `if` rather than another `else if`). The way you have it now the neither branch could only be taken `if(a == b)`